Does an NEC load calculation overage mandate a service upgrade?
I am doing my own load calculation for a new house that I want to add a few premium features into (floor heater, jet tub, induction cooktop, etc.).
Running the NEC 220 calculator, I'm coming out to about 204A.


Is that going to absolutely force me to upgrade to Class 320 400A service? Or is there some wiggle room here when the utility looks at my request for 200A service?

I heard about 225A service. Is that an option with most utilities? I could not find any meter panel of this size. Standard residential equipment is either 200A or Class 320/400A. It seems like anything besides these two options would be unusual and expensive.



Almost 26A (@ 240V) is from all those extra heaters. Why? And why 30A of EVSE provision? Unless required by law (some places have some crazy rules) you can drop that to 20A and still have a usable circuit for when you get an EV.

Intersting. I did some digging into CEC's mandate. Technically, an outlet is not required. Just says that space needs to be reserved in the panel for an EV charger.
Maybe I can get away with installing a low power Level2 (20A @ 240V).
As for the heaters....because floor heating is premium :D
But really because I'm trying to avoid investment into a propane tank + running gas lines + forced air heating in my very very cold area

Actually level2 charging can be up to 40A. So I'm not sure if limiting it to 20A is a good idea, it will trip if I ever plug in a mobile charger that tries to draw more. So I guess this makes my situation worse.

@Shubham if you use a hardwired smart charger with active whole-house monitoring it will reduce the charging current dynamically. Then you can discount the entire EVSE charging current.

Damn, I'm pretty sure I'd get a number about half as big doing it to ASNZS3000. That's insane. 7.5kVA of lighting? Assume full load simultaneously on cooktop, oven, and 75% of microwave/dishwasher?

@someone, yeah it seems like a lot but that number gets discounted to 5.6kVA including laundry and 2 small appliances. It's the standard template that county and review and utility looks at for everyone so it's hard to argue against the methodology.

Maybe you could prioritize your needs. With that, eliminating loft floor heater at 900VA would save 9A(?) Or, whirlpool at 1650VA(!?!?)/14A. This would bring you below the 200A limit (to meet code). Even though your calculated max is 204A, the S/W still recommended 200A service? Seems like wiggle room is built in. Or, smart home control could enforce against unlikely combos (e.g.) loft heat + whirlpool simultaneously.  But, in practice, you'll never use 100% simultaneously. And, [per ratchet freak], heat pump for floor heat would be a boon.

Eliminating luxuries on paper would be the fall back plain. But want to see if there is wiggle room to include them upfront because things like floor heaters are harder to install later.

@Shubham: How about "just install lower power floor heaters".  It'll take them longer to get to target temperature, but they still ought to be able to maintain it just as well.  And the longer ramp-up can be dealt with by smart scheduling.

I don't know if it's possible to switch between series and parallel wiring of resistive underfloor runs after installation, but that is fairly common option on things like water heaters at manufacture (to support multiple voltages from a single SKU) and would let you choose after the fact which rooms get full or lower power.

As of the 2020 NEC, you can't derate the bathroom or kitchen vent fans because they're under 500 W.

You'll have to give them a call and discuss it with them. To be careful of the upsell though. That form already does some rounding it looks like the recommendation is 200A service.
There are a few things you can use to discount some of those loads.
Heatpumps can be used for floor heating as well. Running waterlines through the floor with the water heated by a heatpump. This system can also augment your tank water heater.
Alternatively you can use home automation to prevent all the floor heat from kicking in at the same time.
There exist smart EVSE that will actively monitor the actual whole-house load and dynamically throttle down the charging current when the bigger loads kick in. This lets you fully discount the charging current from the load calculation.

EV, heated floor, and storage water heater definitely seem like things that could be placed on load control.

The recommendation is manually input by me, not automatic.
Trying to avoid hydronic floor heating. Very expensive to install under/inside wood subfloor. Would never break even for 20 years compared to running space heaters all day long.
I wonder if I can include some notes about using load control to convince the utility that 5% overage is ok because loads will never kick in at the same time?

@Shubham -- if your costs of hydronic floor heating are based on the ol' gypcrete screed, I reckon you should take a look at WarmBoard instead (no affiliation, but it seems to be a better solution to the "hydronic floor radiant on a wood subfloor" problem)

@Shubham -- this may be a case where you can look at a "smart panel" upgrade, as those are starting to become practical now for load management...

Take a load diet.
Technology Connections talks about this on their "fully electrify on 100A service" pair of videos.
Right off the bat, tank water heater goes away and gets replaced by a PURE (not "hybrid") heat pump water heater, becoming 1500W.
You should get some space on 220.55, rarely does cooking equipment calculate over 8000 VA.
All those over 8000 watts of last-century electric resistance floor heaters, bye bye! Replace with hydronic/water loop fed by an R290 monobloc heat pump of maybe 2000 watts.
EV charging - this is my favorite -- GONE!  Byebye.  Right out of the Load Calculation. Using EVEMS / Dynamic Load Management and readily available hardwired EV stations well under $1000.  This also unbridles charging speed, max speed is now 11,520 watts (300 miles a night) using common kit, and 19,200 watts (500 miles a night) using exotic kit.
Not that charging "needs" unbridling - 20A/240V (4800W circuit giving 3840W charge) is still 100 miles a night, and that's plenty for 95% of people.  That's 36,000 miles a year, 3 times what most drive.
Well, if you had more EVs maybe.  Right now, we have Power Sharing where you allocate a fixed block of power (say 30A) to the lot and they split it dynamically as cars plug in and finish. We can't YET do Power Sharing on top of dynamic load management, but that's in the pipeline. Europe has had this for a few years, and it works fine.
For now my recommendation is 1 very small station (240V/15A) for minimum bite out of the Load Calc (2.88 kW), and one large EVEMS/DLM station.  And of course level 1 charging for 3rd cars and beyond. Then you just make judicious choices of which car gets the big station tonight.
Use NEC 220.82 Alternate Method not standard method.
The standard method is for everything from dockyards to refineries to malls.  220.82 is specifically made for dwellings and tends to give more favorable numbers.
I recommend Sacramento's worksheet which captures 220.82 accurately. Note EVs are a 100% load.
For instance I see you have almost everything below line 3 being computed as a 75% or 100% load.  That is required for EV charging and air conditioning/heat pumps in NEC 220.82, however electric space heating is a 65% load and everything else is a 40% load.
